# Does Team System Test support running tests under a specific identity?

Tags: unit-testing, security, testing

Is it possible to configure unit tests in Team System Test to run under a specific identity (similar to runas)?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not aware that it is (I don't think it is), you should seriously consider whether your code can be generalized to work against the [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) interface instead of relying on the current WindowsIdentity.

This makes your code a whole lot more flexible, and also makes unit testing a lot simpler because then you can assign any IPrincipal implementation (such as GenericPrincipal) to Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Just remember to do proper Fixture Teardown after each test case. Here's a typical example from one of our test suites:

```
[TestClass]
public class AuditServiceTest
{
    private IPrincipal originalPrincipal;

    public AuditServiceTest()
    {
        this.originalPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TeardownFixture()
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = this.originalPrincipal;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = 
            new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity("Jane Doe", null));
        // More test code
    }
}
```

That said, there are scenarios where impersonation in a "unit" test might be warranted. The ways I've seen this done in MSTest is by writing explict impersonation code in the test cases.

Comment: Hi Mark - Nice Response!

For my particular scenario I am doing an Intranet site where I utilize Kerberos Authentication in IE, and ASP.Net uses impersonation to act on the user's behalf to access SQL.  So I don't think a Generic Principle would work in my scenario.

Comment: That's right - that's why I included that little caveat in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like Team Test has this ability.  I ended up coding my unit test to impersonate the user [using this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx) wrapper for calling the LogonUser Win32 API.

Now my unit test is like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Assert_Access_Denied()
{
    bool denied = false;

    using (new Impersonator("SomeValidUserWithNoAccess", "SomeTestDomain", "SomeTestPassword"))
    {                
        try
        {
            // access some method that performs windows auth
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException exc)
        {
            denied = true;
        }
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(denied);
}
```